# Get a Gif File from URL and Send It via a Discord Bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, gif

As the name suggests, I want to send an gif image with my Discord bot when I say “!radar”. The gif is located at https://radar.weather.gov/ridge/standard/CONUS_0.gif

**Code**

```
import os, discord, requests, json
from base64 import b64decode
from discord.ext import commands

DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents= discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("message was: " + message.content)
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == '!radar':
        url = 'https://radar.weather.gov/ridge/standard/CONUS_0.gif'
        r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
        response_parsed = json.loads(r)
        thumbnail_bytes = b64decode(response_parsed['thumbnailBase64'])
        await message.channel.send(file=thumbnail_bytes)
@client.command()
async def ng(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Pong!')

def start():
    client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/StormyBot/venv/lib/python3.10 /site-packages/discord/client.py", tine 441, in _r un_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/StormyBot/bot.py", tine 21, i n on_message
    response_parsed = json.loads(r)
  File "inix/store/hd4cc9rh83j291r5539hkf6qd8lgiik b-python3-3.10.8/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", tine 339, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `r`?

Comment: Yes, it gave me an enormous string.

Comment: can you share that string? Else we can't really understand what is going on.

Comment: The string is too long to send. It is a lot of …/e792/x558… kind of format. (guessing this is the encoded image). I also have found my answer, but I cannot accept it until tomorrow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IT IS POSSIBLE

Here’s how ~

We can fetch the gif and save it to the directory (will overwrite every time) with `urllib`.

Then we simply post an image with the bot as usual. (Found my basis at [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-open-an-image-from-the-url-in-pil/amp/))

Here is the final code:

```
import os, discord, requests, json, urllib.request
from base64 import b64decode
from discord.ext import commands

DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents= discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("message was: " + message.content)
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == '!radar':
        urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://radar.weather.gov/ridge/standard/CONUS_loop.gif', "rdr.gif")
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('rdr.gif'))
@client.event
async def ng(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Pong!')

def start():
    client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the line `r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)` you are getting a [Response object](https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/ref_requests_response.asp), not a JSON.

try `response_parsed = json.loads(r.json())`, it should solve the problem.

Comment: Nope. It says “json decode error: expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)”

Comment: Then your premises are wrong and you are not getting a JSON to begin with. Indeed, your link is pointing to a GIF image, an image is not a JSON.

Answer (score 1):

That URL doesn't return JSON at all, it's just a GIF (*as the file extension suggests*). You can't parse/load it as JSON, and you can't get its `thumbnailBase64` field. Because it's a GIF. And not a JSON file.

Comment: So in other words I cannot post a gif, only `png/jpgs`?

Comment: No. In other words, **you already have the GIF in your response**, not a JSON object...